# How to decide on the kernel to use for dilations (OpenCV/Python)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, image-processing

I'm very new to OpenCV and recently, I'm trying to compare two images of rails, one with a train and one without. After the comparison, I apply a threshold, and there are some 'holes' in the white regions which I do not want. Currently, I am using dilation with 4 iterations and kernel set to "None", which defaults to a 3x3 by my understanding.

How do I decide what sort of kernel to use so that the dilation does a better job at making the white region continuous? Would also be nice if I could remove the small white blobs in the background. Here is the code:

```
resized = imutils.resize(img2, width=1050)
resized2 = imutils.resize(img3, width=1050)
grayA = cv2.cvtColor(resized, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
grayB = cv2.cvtColor(resized2, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
grayA = cv2.GaussianBlur(grayA,(7,7),0)
grayB = cv2.GaussianBlur(grayB,(7,7),0)
frameDelta = cv2.absdiff(grayA, grayB)
thresh = cv2.threshold(frameDelta, 20, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]
thresh = cv2.dilate(thresh, None, iterations=4)
```

[image]

Complete beginner in this, so even general tips/advice to improve these comparisons would be vastly appreciated!

Comment: You can use a kernel size about the size of the holes you want to fill or the spots you want to remove or you can iterate a number of times with a small kernel to fill or remove where the number of iterations would be approximately the size of the hole divided by the size of the filter.

Comment: Couple questions:
1) How would the dilate function help remove the spots?
2) How do I find, or estimate the size of the holes in the given image?
3) I've tried a very large number of iterations as well (10), and it didn't really fill the holes. It just made the white region itself bigger.

Comment: @John 1)[Dilation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dilation_(morphology)), 2) [structuring Element](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structuring_element) , 3)[OpenCV Tutorial](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d9/d61/tutorial_py_morphological_ops.html).

Comment: @Bilal I don't get it. What structuring element/size would work well for the given example? The 'holes' don't seem to be circular or crosses or squares. And I am confused about what it means to set the kernel the size of the holes. In this case, rather than several small holes, it is more like one big rectangular hole, or one line where the width decreases as we travel along it starting from the bottom.

Comment: @John what I understood from your question is that you want to make a one single mask to the train region (so I recommend to use `closing` instead of `dilation`, to get rid of the small points you can use `Median Filter` instead of `Gaussian Filter`, regarding the kernel size, one solution is to loop with variable kernel size until you reach 2 regions `background`, and `mask`.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I want, thanks. What about the structuring element itself? Also, is there an automatic way to detect if there are 2 regions? I am a bit skeptical of the looping approach because there are (at least) 3 variables in play here : kernel size, kernel shape, number of iterations, and it isn't clear to me whether it is better to use a large kernel size with a small number of iterations or vice versa, or somewhere in the middle with a custom kernel.

Comment: @John automatic way to detect if there are 2 regions `len(np.unique(mask))==2`, the rest you have to try and see which parameters best suits your needs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps this will give you some idea about morphology in Python/OpenCV. First I use a square "open" kernel about the size of the small white spots to remove them. Then I use a horizontal rectangle "close" kernel about the size of the black gap to fill it.  "Open" removes white regions (or fills black gaps) and close removes black regions (or fills white gaps)

Input:

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# read image as grayscale
img = cv2.imread('blob3.png', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

# threshold to binary
thresh = cv2.threshold(img, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]

# apply morphology open with square kernel to remove small white spots
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (19,19))
morph1 = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel)

# apply morphology close with horizontal rectangle kernel to fill horizontal gap
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (101,1))
morph2 = cv2.morphologyEx(morph1, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)

# write results
cv2.imwrite("blob3_morph1.png", morph1)
cv2.imwrite("blob3_morph2.png", morph2)

# show results
cv2.imshow("thresh", thresh)
cv2.imshow("morph1", morph1)
cv2.imshow("morph2", morph2)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Morphology Square Open:

[image]

Morphology Rectangle Close:

[image]

Alternate Morphology Square Close:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! This is pretty much exactly what I wanted. May I ask how you decided on the size/structure of the structural elements? Is it just because the white dots were square-ish, and the white gaps were horizontal-ish? And how did you estimate that the size of the square kernel, for example, should be 19x19?

Comment: Yes, the blobs were square or rectangular. If I had circular regions, I would have used an ellipse with equal radii or elongated ellipse depending upon shape of blob.  The size of the kernel is approx the size of the blob. At the end I tried to get the smallest kernel that would do the job. So some trial and adjust.